# Inserting data into access database through asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I am using following code for inserting data into access database through asp.net (c#) but found error that error in INSERT INTO statement.. 
here problem is just the date..
How can we convert date into format like this #dd-mmm-yyyy#. because it allows this but i m not finding any way to convert date in this format.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO order(orderDesc, orderType, orderCost, orderQty, orderContent, orderStatus, orderDate, orderShipDate, orderDeposit) VALUES (@desc,@type,@cost,@qty,@content,@status,@date,@shipdate,@deposit)";

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query,conn);
        cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", "");
        cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "");
        cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", 34);
        cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", 2);
        cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", "");
        cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "");
        cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToOADate());
        cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shipdate", DateTime.Now.ToOADate());
        cmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deposit", 34);
        cmm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        TextBox1.Text = "Success";
```

this static query works:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO [ORDER] (orderDesc, orderType, orderCost, orderQty, orderContent, orderStatus, orderDate, orderShipDate, orderDeposit) VALUES ('uhgu', 'sagu', 34.5, 4, 'dsg', 'dgs', #23-Mar-2323# , #23-Mar-2323#, 23)";
```

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: what is the field type of `orderDate` and `orderShipDate` fields in the database table?

Comment: Dates always suck, try just using DateTime.Now, you probably tried that though. Maybe do Datetime.Now.ToString(0:d) <- not sure if that is the correct syntax, but google DateTime to string and that might help you.

Comment: field type is date/time for both

Comment: then you should be using `DateTime.Now` as parameter values

Comment: DateTime.Now not working. still getting the same error

Comment: You still haven't told us what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("#dd-MMM-yyyy#");
```

Comment: I need date/time object not string.

Comment: Then you have to rephrase your question and explain what you want, because the format that I showed is exactly what you described. You said you wanted to format DateTime, that means represent it as string of certain form. Nevertheless, parameterized query should not need this, but since you are keeping the error you receive a secret, you reduce your changes of getting help dramatically.

Comment: sorry but i need to insert the date object in format #dd-mmm-yyyy# not string object as it will not accept string in place of date/time

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is "date object", #dd-mmm-yyyy# is its string representation - I sense that we got stuck on terminology here, but I give up, because I am not willing to guess the error that you don't want to disclose.

Comment: I want to disclose my error just because of it I have asked here this question otherwise I will not. But its ok if you cant give me solution..Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Your question does not contain the error/exception message, neither does any of your comments. If you want help in solving an error, at least take an effort to tell people what the error is.